# How to send a command to an Actor in sharded Akka Cluster from "outside"?

Tags: akka, sharding, akka-cluster

Considering we have two services:

- Service1: Sharded Akka Cluster formed by an Akka app with enabled clustering and sharding
- Service2 (not Akka-based): sends commands to sharded Akka Cluster (Service1)

What should be the code in Service2 to send commands to Actors in Service1?

Also, is it possible to make Service2 a part of Service1 (Akka cluster)? also considering that we need to maintain only one instance of Service2. For example, with the use of Akka cluster node roles?

Comment: Not sure why the question was downvoted. Akka documentation is lacking on the aspect of external communications of the cluster. I've done the research, haven't found directly related information.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if components outside of Service1 want to interact with Service1, Service1 should either expose HTTP/GRPC endpoints (Akka HTTP and Akka GRPC are well-suited for this, but any HTTP/GRPC framework could work) or subscribe to a message broker (e.g. Kafka or Pulsar (Alpakka Kafka and pulsar4s have Akka integrations)).

In general, the frameworks I listed above expose a stream of requests/messages, so an outline of code in Service1 would be

```
 val parallelism = ??? // how many commands in flight from the stream
 source
   .map(constructCommand)
   .mapAsync(parallelism) { cmd =>
     futResponseTo(cmd)
   }
```

With the responses being sent back over HTTP/GRPC or published to a Kafka/Pulsar topic which Service2 is listening to.  If the commands are more fire and forget, you could have:

```
source
  .map {
    sendCommand(constructCommand(_))
  }
  .runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

It's possible to merge Service2 and Service1.  It's generally not a good idea to have multiple services running in the same Akka cluster: you're largely throwing away the benefits of decomposition into Service1 and Service2 (most notably the ability to deploy one without deploying the other).

Comment: Thank you Levi, all great points. Regarding "It's possible to merge Service2 and Service1." - how could this be done, considering we would always need just one instance of Service2 in Akka cluster, while Service1 may have multiple instances as a part of the same cluster?

Comment: If you want a single instance of something within an Akka Cluster, Cluster Singleton is well-suited to that.